# Apache ignite continuous query for sqlfieldQuery in c++

Tags: c++, ignite, continuous

We are using Apache Ignite `SqlFieldQuery`. Does continuous query supports `SqlFieldQuery`? Am looking for some example related to this.

Query looks like:

```
Cache<int32_t, std::string> cache = 
    ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int32_t, std::string>(CACHE_NAME);

std::string sql("INSERT INTO \"DG\".TestList (empid,name) values(11, 'name')");

SqlFieldsQuery orgQry(sql);
cache.Query(orgQry);
```

How to get notification for above query using continuous query ?

Comment: Continuous query implementation guarantees exactly once delivery of an event to the client's local listener. Notification can get be get through these 3 methods. https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries#section-local-listener

Example can be found at this location.
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/cpp/examples/continuous-query-example/src/continuous_query_example.cpp
SqlFieldQuery example casn be found at this https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/sql-queries#section-field-queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `ContinuousQuery` for that. Something like this:

```
// Assuming your key type is int32_t
class Listener : public event::CacheEntryEventListener<int32_t, TestList>
{
public:
    virtual void OnEvent(const CacheEntryEvent<int32_t, TestList>* evts, uint32_t num)
    {
        // Simply printing events here. You can put your processing code here.
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "Queried entry [key=" << evts[i].GetKey()
                      << ", val=" << (evts[i].HasValue() ? evts[i].GetValue() : "<none>")
                      << ']' << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Ignite ignite = Ignition::Start(cfg);

    Cache<int32_t, TestList> cache = 
        ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int32_t, TestList>(CACHE_NAME);

    // Declaring listener.
    Listener<int32_t, TestList> listener;

    // Declaring continuous query.
    continuous::ContinuousQuery<int32_t, TestList> qry(MakeReference(listener));

    continuous::ContinuousQueryHandle<int32_t, TestList> handle = 
        cache.QueryContinuous(qry);

    std::string sql("INSERT INTO \"DG\".TestList (empid,name) values(11, 'name')");

    SqlFieldsQuery orgQry(sql);
    cache.Query(orgQry);

    // Waiting here to get notifications.
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I've skipped some boilerplate code. You may find fully functional code example [here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/cpp/examples/continuous-query-example/src/continuous_query_example.cpp)

Comment: Thanks you for the response. What we are actually looking for is , we have multiple tables like TestList, EmployeeData, Organization etc. We are looking for a generic code to get notification whenever there is any modifications to above tables(update, insert or delete). How do to pass the key and value fields to continuous::ContinuousQuery<int32_t, TestList> and CacheEntryEvent<int32_t, TestList> generically. Is there a way to achieve this using continuous query.